# Getting error messages using Joomla on XAMPP

Tags: xampp, joomla

I installed Joomla 1.7 on XAMPP 1.7.4, but it's not working. It's showing me a bunch of messages like:

> Strict Standards: Static function JDatabase::test() should not be
>   abstract in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\libraries\joomla\… on line 350
>
> Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non
>   static in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\libraries\joomla\… on line 394

What can I do to remove those messages?

Comment: Uninstall and install again. Read the messages during install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this right after `define( '_JEXEC', 1 );` on index.php:

```
error_reporting( E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING );
```

You may need to do that on your administrator folder too.